# UIView-Encapsulated-Layout with UICollectionView in UIViewController embed in view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, autolayout

For some reason, using a collection view inside a view controller which is embeded throws UIView-Encapsulated-Layout on the collection views constraints.. i can't set height or top/bottom margins,

Any ideas as to why this happens?

I've been adding constraints through storyboard, I've even tried adding them programmatically

Comment: Try setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.

Comment: I've tried that, i even tried adding the constraints programmatically

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu It seems to only do it when I haven't got a hard coded height, I also found that when its embedded calling to retrieve the bounds of the collection view on the parent viewDidLoad doesn't get the correct size, something for you to keep in mind! My advise is to programmatically add it as a child view and add the constraints

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu also another issue I had along the way is when using custom layouts with mathematically calculated sizes caused issues with the embedded view because the view seems to load at a different times, so using the size of the collection view to calculate the size of cells and spacing always had the wrong results

Comment: @bevbomb thank you a lot for your feedback. I've been struggling with this issue for two days, hope it works now :)